# Mask some digit of Credit Card number in password format

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I'm trying to mask Credit Card number in password format in text field.

`**** **** **** 1234`

Does anyone know of a definitive, reliable way to find this?

Comment: So you want to partially mask the card number. Right?

Comment: No, I want for MasterCard(16), Visa(13,16) and Discover(16)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep all the numbers in one `input`, you can do something like this:

```js
$("#ccNr").keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode != 8){
    var length = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,"").length;
    if(length < 12){
       var val = "";
       for(var i = 0; i < length + 1; i++){
          val+="*";
        if((i+1)%4 == 0){
            val+=" ";
          }
       }
       $(this).val(val);
    }
    if(length < 12 || length >= 16){
        e.preventDefault();       
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ccNr">
```

This can definitely be improved. I just wanted to illustrate the idea. The main thing is to override the default behaviour of the `keydown` event. The `e.keyCode != 8` check makes sure that the key pressed isn't the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key. You should probably check for some other keys as well if you're going to use this. Also, you may want to ignore non-numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could make the first three input types to be of type password and the last one to be text:

```js
function input_onchange(me) {
    if (me.value.length < me.getAttribute('maxlength') - 1) {
        return;
    }
    var i;
    var elements = me.form.elements;
    for (i = 0, numElements = elements.length; i < numElements; i++) {
        if (elements[i] == me) {
            break;
        }
    }
    elements[i + 1].focus();
}
```

```html
<form action="post.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="password" value="" id="first" size="4" maxlength="4"
        onkeypress="input_onchange(this)"/>
    <input type="password" value="" id="second" size="4" maxlength="4"
        onkeypress="input_onchange(this)"/>
    <input type="password" value="" id="third" size="4" maxlength="4"
        onkeypress="input_onchange(this)"/>
    <input type="text" value="" id="fourth" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send Credit Card"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Nehal, I want  to use one input only, becoz I am using Angular Material validation.